# Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>' in React js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am passing an onChange event as a props to a component But I am getting datatype error.

Parent Component -

```
const onChangeStatus=(selectType:string , e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const { options } = e.target;
        console.log(options)
    }

<GlobalSearchAssignmentFilter
                    onChangeAssignmentStatus={onChangeStatus}
                />
```

Child Component -
I have defined an interface like

```
interface A {
    onChangeAssignmentStatus: (
        selectType: string,
        event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    ) => void;
}
```

component code -

```
<Select
   multiple
   native
   onChange={
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):void => onChangeAssignmentStatus(ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_PROPERTY , event)
   }
   inputProps={{
       id: 'select-multiple-native',
   }}
 >                             
   {assignmentFilterData.assignmentDispositions.map(
      (item: any) => (
         <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>
               {item.key}
         </option>
    ))}
</Select>
```

I am importing Select from Material UI multi select. I am getting error when I am passing onChangeAssignmentStatus event to child component. The error is -

```
Type '(selectType: string, e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(selectType: string, event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>'.
      Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLSelectElement': length, options, selectedIndex, selectedOptions, and 3 more.
```

How can I resolve this error ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `onChangeStatus` function, you are expecting `e` to be of type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>`.

However, in your `interface A`, you set the type of `event` to `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`.

These two types do not match, that's why you get the error.

If you want to fix the error, modify the parameter `e` in your `onChangeStatus` function to have the type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` like this:

```
const onChangeStatus=(selectType:string , e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { options } = e.target;
        console.log(options)
}
```

Or modify your `interface A` so the parameter `event` of the function `onChangeAssignmentStatus` is of type `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>` like this:

```
interface A {
    onChangeAssignmentStatus: (
        selectType: string,
        event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>
    ) => void;
}
```

Also, you could set the type of `onChangeStatus` to match the one in `interface A`. This way typescript tells you exactly what type the parameters should be. If you want to do this, you can access the type of `onChangeAssignmentStatus` with `A['onChangeAssignmentStatus']`.